# Binding and style doesn't work for Win8?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I derived from a TextBox and called it MyTextBox.
On my LayoutAwarePage I created 2 SolidColorBrush props: MyBackground and MyBorder.
In the Xaml of that page I wrote a ResourceDictionary with style to the control MyTextBox:

```
 <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="a:MyTextBox">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding MyBackground}"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding MyBorder}"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False"></Setter>
                <Setter  Property="BorderBrush" Value="3"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

When I run this page I can't see the control.
I didn't forget to create a DataContext for the page, and the properties are true colors (not black).
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I doubt [binding in the Setter is not supported.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/3b0f03e2-ab3e-4417-9134-91c3e47fee34/does-stylesetter-propertyvalue-binding-not-work)

Answer (score 1):

Binding in Style Setters is not supported in WinRT.

Comment: If you *must* use Binding, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/11/02/as-the-platform-evolves-so-do-the-workarounds-better-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better-er.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="a:MyTextBox">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MyBackground}"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MyBorder}"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False"></Setter>
                <Setter  Property="BorderBrush" Value="3"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

Try this

And inside App.xaml do

`<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>`

And create a file called standard styles inside your common dir and declare your brushes there (you can actually declare everything there

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Compiler say: "The resource MyBackground cannot be resolved.

Comment: What I'm Trying to do is to build my own DataGrid. I want the color of each column to be different. I also want to randomize the colors, and that's why I don't want MyBackground to be a const.

Comment: @Xyroid: Why is that?  #Tal: then you are barking up the wrong tree bud. Have a look at Datatemplates and datatemplate selectors