# Catastrophic failure in xaml binding

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, windows-10, itemscontrol

I am developing Windows 10 Universal App. I have code below:

xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyProject.BlankPage1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyProject"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="Purple"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="50" Height="50"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Page>
```

and code behind:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public sealed partial class BlankPage1 : Page
    {
        public BlankPage1()
        {
            DataContext =
                new[]
                {
                    new { X = 50.0, Y = 100.0 },
                    new { X = 220.0, Y = 170.0 }
                };
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, the rectangles does not show in the window. I am getting compilation error:

```
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
```

Assigning to Canvas coordinates static numbers in xaml works as expected.

Why error occurs and code does not work?

Comment: You're missing an ItemsSource Binding for your ItemsControl.  Though, setting the DataContext to an array is also somewhat odd; just for testing, I'm assuming?

Comment: Off course it was, thanks for your advice.

Comment: Please clarify: does the problem still occur now that you've added the `ItemsSource` binding to your control? If so, have you tried using a named type instead of an anonymous type? E.g. `Tuple<double, double>` or your own user-defined type? Have you tried seeing the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties in the `ItemTemplate` instead of the content presenter's style?

Comment: Still does not work and same results. Tried with user-defined type and content presenter style replaced with `ItemTemplate` properties. What do you mean by using `Tuple<double, double>`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have VS2015 yet and can't even attempt to reproduce your exact error. Given that you write that it's a "compilation error" (i.e. occurs before you can even run the program, never mind show a window), I don't see why you'd expect anything to "show in the window". That said, I have a vague recollection that you cannot specify a binding for a setter's `Value` in Winrt apps. It works in WPF, but not in Winrt. You may want to consider using `Rectangle.RenderTransform` to position your rectangles instead.

Comment: See also [Binding and style doesn't work for Win8?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18275796). I don't know whether this is the cause of your catastrophic error (I can't repro with Winrt/Universal on Windows 8), but even if you could fix that, I don't think the code you've posted would work.

Comment: @peter-duniho: Described error is on the `Error List` in Visual Studio. Isn't it list of compilation errors? Off course it does not make sense to run app after compilation error, but it seems to be allowed. If I am mistaken, correct me and explain what actually happens, please. Your solution from another SO question seems to be some kind of workaround, but it seems to be too complicated when my issue is really simple. If you know, could you explain my why it does not work just binding with `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` outside of styles?

Comment: I tried `Rectangle.RenderTransform`. It works as expected!

Comment: Yes, it's confusing that VS sometimes allows you to run the code even when an error occurs during compilation. In my experience, these aren't true errors, but rather bugs or deficiencies in the designer/IDE (i.e. it's not fully realizing your code during design-time, so some important state is not set up and causes the error). You are correct that the work-around proposed in the [Binding and style doesn't work for Win8?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18275796) answer is fairly complicated. For your needs, since `RenderTransform` solves the actual immediate goal, I think that's a better approach.

Comment: You already have it working, but for others coming across this post, there is an example of using `RenderTransform` for just this kind of scenario here: [Convert Shape into reusable Geometry in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28338925). I'm not comfortable closing this question as a duplicate, as I was never able to reproduce the original problem, but you should consider closing it yourself as a duplicate of either the "Binding and style..." question or the "Convert Shape into reusable..." question, depending on which one you think most closely fits your original problem.

Comment: As far as why this doesn't work just binding with `Canvas.Left`/`Top` "outside of styles", I don't know exactly what you mean; the problem here is binding _in_ a style (or rather, more specifically, in a `Setter`). There's no problem using binding _outside_ of styles, other than of course the difficulty in getting access to the element that actually needs its `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties set (thus the point of the work-around seen in the "Binding and style..." question, allowing the binding to stay in the style).

Comment: If you're asking why Winrt doesn't support the binding in the setter, I don't know, other than that Winrt is based on Silverlight/Win. Phone instead of WPF as it should have been. IMHO that was a **major** error on Microsoft's part, but I can't answer why they did it specifically other than "not using their noodle". Years ago, it might have made sense to use the drastically trimmed-down version of WPF that is Silverlight, but by the time Winrt showed up, we had hardware that could easily support a full WPF feature set. Living with 10-year-old limitations in a new API is painful and stupid.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this issue myself, while building a Universal Windows Platform app.

Did some googling, found [this](https://aventuraspuntonet.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mixing-style-setters-and-bindings-in-winrt/) article.

It was very helpful. I copied his `SetterValueBindingHelper` class into my own project. After that, I made 1 adjustment, because

```
type = System.Type.GetType(item.Type).GetTypeInfo();
```

gave an exception when you do `Type="Canvas"` in the XAML binding. It first tries to find the class `Canvas` in the current assembly. This returns `null`, and then it calls `.GetTypeInfo()` throwing a NullReferenceException.

Implemented C# 6.0's new `Null-Conditional Operator` on it, and that solved this issue. The code immediately after checks if `type` is null, and then goes through all loaded assemblies to find the `Canvas`.

```
type = System.Type.GetType(item.Type)?.GetTypeInfo();
```

His second usage example is oddly specifically related to using it with a `Canvas` element.

> Another example from my Project VisualDesigner:

Here's my final XAML, based on his example:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding CanvasItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="helpers:SetterValueBindingHelper.PropertyBinding">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <helpers:SetterValueBindingHelper>
                        <helpers:SetterValueBindingHelper Type="Canvas" Property="Left" Binding="{Binding WindowX, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <helpers:SetterValueBindingHelper Type="Canvas" Property="Top" Binding="{Binding WindowY, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </helpers:SetterValueBindingHelper>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <applicationwindow:ApplicationWindow Width="{Binding WindowWidth}" Height="{Binding WindowHeight}" DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

`helpers:` refers to the namespace the `SetterValueBindingHelper` is in. `ApplicationWindow` in my case is a custom UserControl. `CanvasItems` is an `ObservableCollection<ApplicationWindowViewModel>`, and this is my `ApplicationWindowViewModel`:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class ApplicationWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public double WindowX { get; set; } = 10;

    public double WindowY { get; set; } = 10;

    public int WindowWidth { get; set; } = 300;

    public int WindowHeight { get; set; } = 200;
}
```

In this example I use [Fody.PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to handle the property changed events on the X/Y/Width/Height properties, if you're not using this package, don't forget to implement your own PropertyChanged event handlers, etc.