# Unable to add binding to UWP DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, datagrid

I want to bind some data to columns created dynamically in my code behind. It's working with `DataGridTextColumn` but not with `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

Since DataGridTemplateColumn doesn't have a "Binding" property, I created a custom column deriving from `DataGridTemplateColumn` as some solutions suggested. However the `SetBinding` throw a System.Exception when GenerateElement method is called and crashes the program.

```cs
class DataGridBoundColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
{
    public BindingBase Binding { get; set; }

protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
{
    var element = base.GenerateEditingElement(cell, dataItem);
    if (element != null && Binding != null)
        element.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, Binding);
    return element;
}

protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
{
    var element = base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
    if (element != null && Binding != null)
        element.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, Binding);//Error is here
    return element;
}
}
```

The code used to create columns and to populate the grid:

```cs
dataGrid.Columns.Add(new Models.DataGridBoundColumn
{
    Header = " Week" + week.WeekNumber,
    Binding = new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("[" + i.ToString() + "]") },
    CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["templateCell"]
});

var collection = new ObservableCollection<object>();
List<string> list = new List<string>(new string[] { "2", "3", "7" });
for (int i= 0; i < list.Count; i++)//Trying with some test data
{
    collection.Add(list);
}
dataGrid.ItemsSource = collection;
```

The `DataTemplate` I'm using for testing at he moment:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="templateCell">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding WeekNumber}" />
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" Width="20" Fill="{Binding ItemColor}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I have looked closely at the binding class documentation, but I have still no clue why it's throwing this exception...

The error is :

> Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF
> (E_UNEXPECTED))
>
> at Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.SetBinding(DependencyProperty dp,
> BindingBase binding)  at
> Application.Models.DataGridBoundColumn.GenerateElement(DataGridCell
> cell, Object dataItem) in  C:...\Models\DataGridBoundColumn.cs:line
> 26 at
> Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid.PopulateCellContent(Boolean
> isCellEdited, DataGridColumn dataGridColumn, DataGridRow dataGridRow,
> DataGridCell dataGridCell)  at
> Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid.AddNewCellPrivate(DataGridRow
> row, DataGridColumn column)  at
> Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid.CompleteCellsCollection(DataGridRow
> dataGridRow)  at
> Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid.GenerateRow(Int32 rowIndex,
> Int32 slot, Object dataContext)  at
> Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid.AddSlots(Int32 totalSlots)
> at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid.RefreshRows(Boolean
> recycleRows, Boolean clearRows)  at
> Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid.RefreshRowsAndColumns(Boolean
> clearRows)  at
> Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid.MeasureOverride(Size
> availableSize)

Comment: Can you please include the full exception message?

Comment: Just added the complete stacktrace

Comment: Thanks. I replaced "Défaillance irrémédiable" with "Catastrophic failure" as I believe it is the correct english translation, please re-edit otherwise!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catastrophic failure in xaml binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290099/catastrophic-failure-in-xaml-binding)

Comment: Saw it earlier, I don't think it's the same issue

Comment: May I know how the week is defined and the layout of the DataGrid? Due to the incomplete code, I cannot reproduce your issue, could you please provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it's working correctly now and it was an easy fix. The issue was the incorrect usage of `Contentproperty`, since my StackPanel (in DataTemplate) doesn't have one it's getting this error. The correct property is `DataContextProperty`.

```cs
  class DataGridBoundColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
   {
     public BindingBase Binding { get; set; }
    
     protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
     {
       var element = base.GenerateEditingElement(cell, dataItem);
       if (element != null && Binding != null)
         element.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.DataContextProperty, Binding);
       return element;
     }
    
     protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
     {
       var element = base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
       if (element != null && Binding != null)
         element.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.DataContextProperty, Binding);
       return element;
     }
   }
```

Thanks to @PeterFleischer-3316 from Microsoft Q&A for solving the issue.