# Positioning XAMLUI elements on ItemsControl with Canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, mvvm, win-universal-app

I'm building a Windows Universal application where I need to put some elements on a canvas. Since I want to do this MVVM style I've read that I should use an ItemsControl for it. Problem is that all the solutions I found are for WPF or Silverlight and don't work for Windows Universal. They appear on the canvas, but they keep positioning themselfs in the left upper corner.

[image: Current result]

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="18"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
             <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}" />
             <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

XAML's code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent(); 
    DataContext = new MyItemViewModel();
}
```

Viewmodel and model:

```
class MyItemViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<MyItem> _myItems;

    public MyItemViewModel()
    {
        _myItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
        _myItems.Add(new MyItem(10, 10, "First TextBlock"));
        _myItems.Add(new MyItem(200, 400, "2nd TextBlock"));
        _myItems.Add(new MyItem(400, 200, "The Third TextBlock"));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems
    {
        get { return _myItems; }
        set { _myItems = value; }
    }
}

public class MyItem
{
    public MyItem(double left, double top, string text)
    {
        Left = left;
        Top = top;
        Text = text;
    }

    public double Left { get; set; }
    public double Top { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290099/catastrophic-failure-in-xaml-binding

Comment: I don't agree. I see the items, but they don't give an exception. They just stay on the top left corner.

Comment: I think your `TargetType` is wrong. Try this instead: `TargetType="{x:Type UIElement}"`. If that doesn't work, try removing the `TargetType` attribute altogether.

Comment: After a brief search it would appear that this type of binding in the style might not be supported in Windows Universal apps (the issue actually dates back to WinRT, and Silverlight before that). See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18275796/4265041), and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33582406/4265041).

Answer (score -1):

Use `FrameworkElement` as the `TargetType` instead:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
         <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}" />
         <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: If you don't use it, it won't compile

Comment: My bad, I thought you were using WPF. Try adding the target type of FrameworkElement.